# Checking an environment variable using the Maven AntRun plugin

Tags: maven, ant, environment-variables, mule

I'm trying to check and see if the MULE_HOME environment variable is set within the maven-antrun-plugin without success.  Here's what I have so far:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mule-deploy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"
                                     classpath="${settings.localRepository}/ant-contrib/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
                            <echo message="MULE_HOME is ${env.MULE_HOME}"/>
                            <if>
                                <isset property="env.MULE_HOME"/>
                                <then>
                                    <echo message="MULE_HOME is set"/>
                                </then>
                                <else>
                                    <echo message="MULE_HOME is not set"/>
                                </else>
                            </if>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

The output is:

```
 [echo] MULE_HOME is /<my development path>/mule
 [echo] MULE_HOME is not set
```

What am I missing to check an environment variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java stores environment variables differently from system properties; System.getenv() vs. System.getProperties().  My guess is that maven isn't mapping environment variables into system properties which is what Ant is expecting with isset.  Try creating a property in your POM:

```
<properties>
    <mulehome>${env.MULE_HOME}</mulehome>
<properties>
```

then use

```
<isset property="mulehome"/>
```

Comment: One clarification: my example will create a maven property in the project, not a system property, but the antrun plugin copies all maven properties into the Ant project before running, so it should work.

Comment: doesnt work. if ${env.MULE_HOME} is not set than mulehome will be set to '${env.MULE_HOME}' as text

Answer (score 0):

After the taskdef line, define a:

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

My Ant memories are a bit rusty, but as far as I recall, you needed to define that first before being able to use ${env.FOO_BAR} variables. I hope this helps. :)