# Why isn't Maven recognizing my environment variables?

Tags: maven, environment-variables, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

I’m Using Maven 3.3.3 on Mac Yosemite with Java 8.  I have defined a variable, JBOSS_HOME, in my /etc/profile file …

```
JBOSS_HOME=/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2
```

In my terminal (using bash shell), I can see the value of this variable …

```
davea$ echo $JBOSS_HOME
/opt/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2
```

However, when I run my Maven script (from the same shell), I can’t access the value of this variable.  The below

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>20020829</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-dodeploy-file</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
                    <property environment="env" />
                    <echo message="jboss home: ${env.JBOSS_HOME}" />
```

produces …

```
 [echo] jboss home: ${env.JBOSS_HOME}
```

What gives?  How do I get Maven to recognize my environment variables?

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610980/checking-an-environment-variable-using-the-maven-antrun-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added this line at the top of my ~/.profile file

```
export JBOSS_HOME=$JBOSS_HOME
```

Then the Maven script picked up the environment variable.  Intuitive, eh?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the line `<property environment="env" />`. As defined in the [Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html), this will read the system environment variables (not the user environment variables) and stores them in properties, prefixed with `"env"`. This will hide the `${env.*}` properties that Maven defines.

As such, this configuration will work:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>20020829</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-dodeploy-file</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
                    <echo message="jboss home: ${env.JBOSS_HOME}" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, I removed the line '<property environment="env" />' but Maven is still not picking up the JBOSS_HOME environment varaible.

Comment: @Dave Hmm, I just tested this on my Windows machine and it worked. What was your output?

Comment: On my Mac, the output was the same as before, "[echo] jboss home: ${env.JBOSS_HOME}"

Comment: @Dave I edited with the full plugin configuration I'm using. When launched with `mvn clean install`, this outputs the correct value.

Comment: Thx.  Still no dice so this probably has to do with teh difference between how Maven runs on Windows vs Mac.  I did find a solution that works in my environment that I'll post in a few.